# How to include asset in a framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, sdk, frameworks

I want to add a new xcassets folder into my framework (there is already xcassets in this framework).

I have four targets :

- one for the projet (workspace) which I build every day for the development
- one for the tests
- one for the SDK, which includes all header, xcassets, files, etc.
- one to build the SDK

[image]

I checked the SDK target on the target membership view (when I'm on the xcassets folder).
I add the xcassets folder in the build phase (like it was for the other).

Now, what I'm missing ?

Here the screenshots : 
The assets folder
[image]

The project
[image]

The SDK
[image]

The SDK Builder
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the assets in the Project's (not the SDK) *Targets - BuildPhase - CopyBundleResources*. I'm not quite sure but you probably need to make sure it has a unique name. i.e If the project has Assets.xcassets, name yours something else.

Comment: It was already in the buildPhase of the project.I change the name, but it's still the same

Comment: You've added the framework under both `Link Binaries With Libraries` and `Embedded Binaries ` as well?

Comment: Also make sure to mark `create folder references` when adding the asset in `CopyBundleResources `

Comment: The framework was already there, it's in the `Link Binaries With Libraries`, but I don't have `Embedded binaries`, I have `Embed Framework (0 items)`. The asset folder was already there too. Maybe I can add screenshot or information for you ?

Comment: Yeah, screenshot can help

Comment: Screenshots available :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166899/discussion-between-pierre-f-and-glaphi).